# How to convert current location of google java script API to text

Tags: geolocation, location, currentlocation

I have tried so many codes but none them is working with respect to coveting  current location to text in search bar please let me know any thing that works for my requirement.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please provide some code examples, so that we can see what exactly doesn't work / thrown errors.

Comment: @ilja currently I don't have any code snippet but I'm looking for one so if there is any code, please let me know. Thanks